# Is there a way to change the color of the button in LightningAlert?

Tags: lightning-web-components, style

[LightningAlert lwc doc reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-alert/documentation)

```
LightningAlert.open({
            message: 'message',
            theme: 'default',
            label: 'Atención:', 
        });
```

If I am invoking this Alert on my js, is there a way to change the color of the button in it? Theme only affects to the header apparently:

> theme: Color theme for the header.

Comment: As a general rule, if you don't find it in the docs, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to change the color of the button in LightningAlert in LWC Salesforce. Although the 'theme' property in LightningAlert only affects the header color, you can use custom CSS to modify the color of the button.

According to a StackOverflow post [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483498/how-can-i-apply-css-in-lightning-buttons-to-change-color)], you can apply CSS to a Lightning button by defining a class inside the button and using that class to change the button's color. For example:

```css
/* Inside your LWC component's CSS file */
.Morning {
  color: red;
}
```

And then in your HTML:

```html
<lightning-button class="Morning" label="Click me"></lightning-button>
```

If you need more customization options, you can use a normal `<button>` element and style it with Salesforce-defined classes and any additional CSS you need. Use the Salesforce Lightning Design System for a consistent look and feel with other Salesforce components [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483498/how-can-i-apply-css-in-lightning-buttons-to-change-color)].

However, please note that the provided solutions are for Lightning buttons in general and not specifically for LightningAlert. You may need to inspect the HTML structure of the LightningAlert component and apply the CSS targeting the button inside the alert accordingly.